# Is there a peak RAM age?

Tags: memory

I'm using a MacBook Pro upgraded to 8GB of RAM. I have an app called Memory Clean in my menu bar that shows how much unused RAM is available. Recently, (about 9 months since RAM installed) I noticed an increase in the amount of free RAM available. Is there such a thing as a "peak" in the efficiency (I don't think that's the right word to use) of RAM over time? Or is it just because of software updates?

Comment: What changed? What updates did you run? Unlike fine wine and cheese, RAM does not get better with age. :-)

Comment: @IconDaemon I've updated to the Yosemite 10.10.4 public beta (build 14E11f, not the latest, 14E11e) and updated the biggest memory hog, Photodesk, to its latest version. I thought there might be something similar to a break-in period with the circuits on the card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Free RAM is wasted RAM. What you want is a large amount of Inactive Memory (called file cache these days), which helps to speed up your computer incase those files are accessed again. I'm sure you think you're speeding up your computer by "cleaning" it, but the only time that's useful is when you've just used a RAM-heavy application that you are certain to not want to relaunch in the near future. Otherwise, there is no benefit, and indeed you are slowing down your overall experience due to not having that file cache sitting around for future use. OS X will use as much RAM as it has access to. Typically, a large portion of it is cache, and so will be freed the moment an app needs it.